# Google Calendar Custom Button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

we're using Google Apps heavily in my company. Now there is a new requirement to set specific settings (prefilled event name, rooms selected, ...) for the event automatically on creation.

This possibility should be available for all users in the company. So I asked myself (and now you also) if there is the possibility to add a custom button to the calendar app? This button could use the e.g. javascript API to create the new event with the prefilled information.

If this is not possible what other ideas do you have?

thanks & regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Calendar App customisation a these days exist as Chrome extensions/plugins (other browsers are available) However, there is a way to install sidebar type tools via hosted XML. This XML can in turn host simple or elaborate web apps.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/

If you are looking for a button anywhere n the Google Calendar UI other than a sidebar then the browser plugin would be your only option.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect for me :)

Comment: Page not found for above link